# Google plus - can we add this for sharing the site content

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[Google +1 button](http://www.google.com/+1/button/), I think, is another one possible way to share the site content to the world.
Can we add this to the right block? Or this is a question for the [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

[image]

Comment: Can I say... +1 to this idea. :D

Comment: It is already on meta.so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97406/any-plans-supporting-google-for-link-sharing-in-the-near-future, go and up-vote that one instead! ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since the issue was raised and addressed in Meta.SE.

Comment: That’s not a close reason. Cross-site dupes aren’t dupes and this is on-topic on meta.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest delete this Q. (a) it has been implemented and (b) although not rolled out simultaneously IMO was a question for META (SE) (where indeed it had already been asked).